# Django 3.0 + Channels + ASGI + TokenAuthMiddleware

Tags: django, django-channels, asgi

I upgraded to Django 3.0 and now I get this error when using websockets + TokenAuthMiddleware:

```
SynchronousOnlyOperation
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you can't access synchronous code from an asynchronous context. Here is a `TokenAuthMiddleware` for Django 3.0:

```
# myproject.myapi.utils.py
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(headers):
    try:
        token_name, token_key = headers[b'authorization'].decode().split()
        if token_name == 'Token':
            token = Token.objects.get(key=token_key)
            return token.user
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        return AnonymousUser()


class TokenAuthMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        return TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance(scope, self)


class TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance:
    """
    Yeah, this is black magic:
    https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1399
    """
    def __init__(self, scope, middleware):
        self.middleware = middleware
        self.scope = dict(scope)
        self.inner = self.middleware.inner

    async def __call__(self, receive, send):
        headers = dict(self.scope['headers'])
        if b'authorization' in headers:
            self.scope['user'] = await get_user(headers)
        inner = self.inner(self.scope)
        return await inner(receive, send)


TokenAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: TokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

Use it like this:

```
# myproject/routing.py
from myapi.utils import TokenAuthMiddlewareStack
from myapi.websockets import WSAPIConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            path("api/v1/ws", WSAPIConsumer),
        ]),
    ),

})
application = SentryAsgiMiddleware(application)
```

Comment: Please mark this as answer. works flawlessly! I wouldn't have wasted hours if I found this before.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore:
`TypeError: __call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'receive' and 'send'`

Comment: This works flawlessly. I just had somes problems later on during deploy using daphne, as it requires django.settings. Just put yourself a reminder that you might need to add os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<yourapp>.settings") /
django.setup() on top of utils.py file (prior to importing rest_framework, jwt, etc) so that they have access to your settings variables.

Answer (score 3):

As @tapion [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009296/django-3-0-channels-asgi-tokenauthmiddleware#comment114523457_60009297) this solution doesn't work anymore since [channels 3.x](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releases/3.0.0.html#update-to-asgi-3)

Newer solution can be a little bit tweaked:

```
class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        headers = dict(scope['headers'])
        if b'authorization' in headers:
            scope['user'] = await get_user(headers)
        return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
```